# Google Sheets app script to hide rows in batch based on the las column of each tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hide, batch-processing

I have a google sheets that have many tabs, some of them have different layouts

I need a script to run on all tabs (and be able to exclude some tabs) to hide the rows that contains 1 in the very last column of every row on each tab

This should be a hide in batch since I have a lot of rows, and if make the hide row by row it exceed the execution time

any help will be very much appreciated

Thanks !

Comment: You should try it by yourself first and post the code. You have info here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to read each sheet, keep track of ranges with rows that have 1 in last column and hide those ranges 1 by 1. Below code tries to do that. See if it works in your case. Put in exact names of sheets you want to exclude inside the `excludes` array.

```
function test() {
  // get spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // get all sheets
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  // put exact sheet names in array to exclude, sample ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']
  var excludes = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    // if sheet is to exclude,do nothing
    if (excludes.indexOf(sheets[i].getName()) != -1) continue;
    // hide rows of this sheet
    hideRows(sheets[i]);
  }
}

function hideRows(sheet) {
  // variables
  var start = null,
    range = 0,
    flag = false;
  // read all values
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // for each row
  values.forEach(function(row, idx) {
    // if row last col is 1, set up start and range
    if (row[row.length - 1] == 1) {
      if (flag) {
        range++;
      } else if (!flag) {
        start = idx + 1;
        range++;
        flag = true;
      }
      return;
    }
    // row last col is not 1, hide last found range of rows
    // reset variables
    if (flag) {
      sheet.hideRows(start, range);
      flag = false;
      start = null;
      range = 0;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make it only in one function ?

Comment: `hideRows(sheets[i]);` line in `test()` function can be replaced with all the contents of `hideRows()` function. but it'll be messy to read. whats wrong with 2 functions ? even more imp, did it work ? were you able to test ?